# Haskell -- Substitute Elements In A List

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have two lists -- one is a grid list of tuples and the other one is a list of coordinates -- to be compared, such that the list of coordinates is always a sublist of the grid list. Now I want to check each tuple in the grid list whether it's in the coordinates list or not. If there exists one, substitute the tuple in the grid list with a "#" and if not, substitute with a "_".

Below is my best attempt and it never works.

```
getHash :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)] -> [String]
getHash [(x1,y1)] [(x2,y2)] | (x1,y1) `elem` [(x2,y2)] : (x1,y1) = "#"
                            | otherwise (x1,y1) = "_"
    where (x1,y1) <- [(x1,y1)]
```

Comment: `[(x1,y1)]` only matches a list containing exactly one pair of coordinates.  If you want to watch an arbitrary list, you will need a single variable name like `xy1` without any brackets or parentheses.  (More generally, you seem to be struggling with having brackets and syntax in inappropriate places.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Should I create a new type for `(x, y)` and use the name `xy1` in the function?

Comment: No, you don't need to create any types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace each element in a list with `"#"` or `"_"` depending on whether that element is an element of a second list. We can split that into two parts. The first part, "Replace each element in a list with the result of calling a function with that element as its argument" is `map`. The second, doing something based on whether an item is an element of a list, does indeed use `elem`. So we will

1. `map` over a list and
2. call `elem` on each element,
3. comparing it with the list of known coordinates, and
4. decide which string to replace the element of the list with based on the result of the call to `elem`.

```
getHash known xs = map (\x -> if x `elem` known then "#" else "_") xs
```

Now, why did I give the known list first? It's mostly personal preference, but I think it works a bit better with partial application. `getHash [(1,2)]` is a function that compares a list given as an argument with a static 'known' list. And since `xs` is the right position for it, we can also use eta reduction in the definition:

```
getHash known = map (\x -> if x `elem` known then "#" else "_")
```